# How to continue a macro after an error is generated

Tags: excel, vba

I have an MS Excel macro that creates a number of PivotTables. The issue is that if a value that I am filtering on no longer exists an error is generated and the macro stops (the rest of the PivotTables are not created). The offending line is:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Test Cycle").CurrentPage = _
    "SIT Cycle 2"
```

If "SIT Cycle 2" has no errors today then it will not be in the source data and an error is thrown in the macro. Instead, I would like to print "Nil" on the active sheet and continue. The macro will eventually create about ten individual PivotTables.

The Macro is:

```
'
' Cycle_2_Severity_by_Status Macro
'

'
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Cycle 2 Severity by Status"
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Table_owssvr__1", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="'Cycle 2 Severity by Status'!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable2", DefaultVersion _
        :=xlPivotTableVersion15
    Sheets("Cycle 2 Severity by Status").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Status")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Severity")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable2").PivotFields("SIR ID"), "Count of SIR ID", xlCount
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Test Cycle")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Test Cycle"). _
        ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Test Cycle").CurrentPage = _
        "SIT Cycle 2"
    Sheets("owssvr (1)").Select
    Range("A2").Select
'
' SIT_CR_Severity_by_Status Macro
'

'
    Sheets.Add
    ActiveSheet.Name = "SIT CR Severity by Status"
    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
        "Table_owssvr__1", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion15).CreatePivotTable _
        TableDestination:="'SIT CR Severity by Status'!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable2", DefaultVersion _
        :=xlPivotTableVersion15
    Sheets("SIT CR Severity by Status").Select
    Cells(3, 1).Select
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Status")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Severity")
        .Orientation = xlColumnField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable2").PivotFields("SIR ID"), "Count of SIR ID", xlCount
    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Test Cycle")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Test Cycle"). _
        ClearAllFilters
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Test Cycle").CurrentPage = _
        "SIT CR"
    Sheets("owssvr (1)").Select
    Range("A2").Select
```

Comment: There is no error handling in the above code. You can use `code` On Error Resume Next    to determine what should happen when errors occurs. Else you can validate with typical if else statment. Like if len(error) <0, then 'do what you want else 'display error msg..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/141571 Glun is correct
You have to take a look at On Error handle.

Comment: Thank you, I know very little about VBA and am on a steep learning curve. Regards, Glyn